# How to monitor a git branch using python?

Tags: python, git

i would like to know if anyone know any library for git that would help me to monitor a git branch for any new commits.
Idea is to check for new commits & read the files impacted, if the impacts are only on .xml or .txt -> "Do Nothing", otherwise i must trigger a jenkins job to build the branch.

Today i have a jenkins job that builds the branch, only thing which is missing is, branch monitoring and the impacted/modified files list.

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might not necessarily need python for this as you can [set the jenkins job to build on a git commit](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/) trigger

Comment: this was already implemented in the past (but we stopped it for following reason), but draw back was that it was triggering for scenarios for which isn't necessary to trigger. if its possible to look for the type of files & launch based on the changes done to the repo would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would probably kick off the Jenkins job on each commit. You can get the list of files modified in Jenkins then modify the build script based on that information.

If you want to do this in Python, then you have a few options:

- [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) standard library to make a call to the `git` utility
- [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) third party library to interact with a Git repository in Python

Regarding the direct Git interaction, `$ git diff --name-only develop..HEAD` will give you the list of files that have changed between the develop branch and the current working directory.